# Can't change the SCOPES in Google Sheets API without getting a 404 error : Requested entity was not found

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I get this error whenever I try running that code : HttpError 404 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1KpJw640oNNwVfEasGoSffrfoyC7i1ryHakdWZmr-AX4/values:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Requested entity was not found.">
I am trying to update a Google Sheet file with the help of this API but the only scope that I manage using is "readonly". I tried deleting the token.pickle file : I get identified so the request isn't requiring authentification credentials. But I don't know why I would still get an error. So basically all I can do is extracting data from a sheet but not overwrite cells.

```
 from __future__ import print_function
 from pprint import pprint
 from googleapiclient import discovery
 import pickle
 import os.path
 from googleapiclient.discovery import build
 from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
 from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

 SCOPES = ['https:// www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'] #what I have changed from the Python Quickstart code from the Google Sheets API website

 creds = None

 if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
 if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server()
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

 service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

 spreadsheet_id = '1KpJw640oNNwVfEasGoSffrfoyC7i1ryHakdWZmr-AX4' #this id is correct and still I get an error

 batch_update_values_request_body = {
     'value_input_option': 'USER_ENTERED',

     'data': [
     {
       "range": "Control Panel!A:B",
       "majorDimension": "ROWS",
       "values": [[1,2]]
     }
    ], 
   }

 request = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, 
 body=batch_update_values_request_body)
 response = request.execute()

 pprint(response)
```